# what is the difference between join activity and lookup in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In the documentation it is mentioned that the lookup activity in azure data flow is similar to join activity with join type equal to left outer join. so i was wondering if both can be used interchangeably or there are some difference between them

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you want to deal with your data.

[Join active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) is to combine data from two sources or streams in a mapping data flow. But [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-lookup) not only can do this, it could has lookup conditions to filter the input stream data.

In most scenarios, lookup and join active can be used interchangeably.

Comment: if i understand correct Lookup does not do filtering to input stream, it is already mentioned in the documentation "A lookup transformation is similar to a left outer join. All rows from the primary stream will exist in the output stream with additional columns from the lookup stream."

Comment: @user2249979 like the document said lookup is the left outer join, but join active support more join options. Also like I said, lookup and join active can be used interchangeably  In most scenarios. It depends on how you want to deal with you source data.

Comment: Hi @user2249979, hope you're doing well,  do you have any other concerns?